# Clojure pipe collection one by one

Tags: clojure

How in Clojure process collections like in Java streams - one by one thru all the functions instead of evaluating all the elements in all the stack frame. Also I would describe it as Unix pipes (next program pulls chunk by chunk from previous one).

Comment: You could use `->` to achieve something similar to Streams. You would just need to have it operate on a lazy collection. This is overly broad for here though. Look up lazy collections and `->`, and post back when you have something specific that we can help you with.

Comment: I missed my edit opportunity, but you'd actually use `->>` when working with collections most of the time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I understand your question, you may want to look into two things.

First, understand the [sequence abstraction](https://clojure.org/reference/sequences). This is a way of looking at collections which consumes them one by one and *lazily*. It is an important Clojure idiom and you'll meet well known functions like `map`, `filter`, `reduce`, and many more. Also the macro `->>`, which was already mentioned in a comment, will be important.

After that, when you want to dig deeper, you probably want to look into [transducers](https://clojure.org/reference/transducers) and [reducers](https://clojure.org/reference/reducers). In a grossly oversimplifying summary, they allow you combine several lazy functions into one function and then process a collection with less laziness, less memory consumption, more performance, and possibly on several threads. I consider these to be advanced topics, though. Maybe the sequences are already what you were looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple example [from ClojureDocs.org](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/-%3E)

```
;; Use of `->` (the "thread-first" macro) can help make code
;; more readable by removing nesting. It can be especially
;; useful when using host methods:

;; Arguably a bit cumbersome to read:
user=> (first (.split (.replace (.toUpperCase "a b c d") "A" "X") " "))
"X"

;; Perhaps easier to read:
user=> (-> "a b c d" 
           .toUpperCase 
           (.replace "A" "X") 
           (.split " ") 
           first)
"X"
```

As always, don't forget [the Clojure CheatSheet](http://jafingerhut.github.io/cheatsheet/clojuredocs/cheatsheet-tiptip-cdocs-summary.html) or [Clojure for the Brave and True](https://www.braveclojure.com/clojure-for-the-brave-and-true/).